# Angular Js - Add Dynamic Data in local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am new to `angular js`, I am using local storage in my project.
I want to store the data in local storage dynamically.

What is the best way to achieve this?

My function is :

```
$scope.saveItem=function(){
    var dataobj= {  'itemCode':vm.person1.selected.itemCode,
                    'itemName':'name',
                    'qty':'1',
                    'price':'2',
                    'total':1 * 2,
                    'comment':'comment',
                   };
    localStorageService.set('order',dataobj);
}
```

I have entered the static data here but this data will be dynamic when I add the new item and I want to keep previous data and store newly entered data in local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code , it works prefectly :

```
    $scope.temp=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(vm.person.selected.cust_id));
    if($scope.temp){
    $scope.order = $scope.temp;
    }else{
    $scope.order=[];
    }   
    localStorage.setItem(vm.person.selected.cust_id, JSON.stringify($scope.order));

    var dataobj={'itemCode':vm.person1.selected.itemCode,
         'itemName':vm.person1.selected.itemName,
         'qty':vm.qty,
         'price':vm.price,
         'total':vm.qty * vm.price,
         'comment':vm.comment,
         'orderType':$scope.heading
         };
    $scope.order.unshift(dataobj);           
    localStorage.setItem(vm.person.selected.cust_id,JSON.stringify($scope.order));
    $scope.allCurrentTakeAwayOrder=$scope.order;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why using a service for localStorage, you can simply use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) native API.
When you add some item just do something like this :

```
var order = localStorage.getItem('order');
if(order) {
   localStorage.setItem('previousOrder', order);
}
localStorage.setItem('order', NEW_ORDER_DATA_HERE);
```

NOTE : A storage item must be a [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) so think about `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` your data before storing and fetching them.